# Sending SMTP Email without Authentication

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

My webhost does not allow mail accounts to be created. However they have provided me with their SMTP gateway and said no credentials are needed when the mails are being sent from their datacenter.

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug    = 2;
$mail->Host         = GATEWAY_PROVIDED_BY_HOST
$mail->SMTPAuth     = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure   = false;
```

> Invalid address: (From): root@localhost

It seems I need to add a from address. But in the case that they do not allow a mail account to be created, what do I put in the from address?

Comment: Show all your code, the error seems to be because your not using `$mail->setFrom();`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tried a random info@mydomain.com and it says `1 Mon, 20 Aug 2018 13:26:09 +0200 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail`

Comment: That's not an error, it's just the SMTP "welcome" banner, doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @Synchro It was followed by 'could not connect to smtp host` after couple of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a valid sender "from" email address.

Update:
You have to use a sender address which is the mail server responsible for (or a white listed one).
normal "@domain.tld" is enought. the name in front of the at is often not tested.

Also possible: you can only send "to" the domain which is the mail server responsible for or you have to authenticate. best is you contact your server provider.

Comment: In the case they do not allow to create an email account, should I use external one?

Comment: I tried info@mydomain.com (although it does not exist) and it gave me an error you can see in my other reply.

Comment: Hi, I think the issue was with SSL, I added this:     `$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );

    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` and part of the issue is fixed. But now I get `SERVER -> CLIENT: 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client (sample.com)` when the to address is info@sample.com.

Comment: When you use this settings you are not safe against man in the middle attacks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a From address:

```
$mail->setFrom('user@example.com', 'My Name');
```

This will set the from address that appears in message headers, but it will also used as the `MAIL FROM` command at the SMTP level (where your error is coming from) as it's automatically copied to the `Sender` PHPMailer property which applies there. That will avoid the fallback to the `root@localhost` address you're getting.

The other things you're doing to disable authentication are correct.

Answer (score -3):

Create a Google Account and use it:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "your@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "*****";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = "465";
$mail->setFrom('your@gmail.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->addReplyTo('your@gmail.com', 'Your Name');
```

Comment: Thanks for Downvote! The first line is: "My webhost does not allow mail accounts to be created.". For this need a 3rd service provider. I think don't have SMTP service on this server.